# Tab pages disappearing as new questions arrive

Tags: bug, questions, new-nav

Since half an hour I experience the following bug: I have saved several tabpages to filter interesting questions like [haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell), [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog), [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java),...

However if a new question arrives on the *active* tab, the tab pages on the right sometimes disappear:

[image: Screenshot, missing tabs]

After reloading (clicking on the gray area), the tab pages appear again:

[image: Screenshot, tabs restored]

This behavior does not occur every time, and I don't know the specific conditions when it happens. It has however already happened three times.

Comment: Related [Retiring New Navigation (beta) in preparation for Navigation 3.0](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359643/383779)