# "Tagged Questions" page not working?

Tags: discussion, support

Up until about 2017/12/04 10:30 PST (18:30 UTC), this link

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java%20xml%20perl%20xslt?mode=any
```

was working just fine.  Now it returns a page like this

[image]

It looks like this on the `newest`, `frequent`, `votes` and `active` tabs.  Is this a permanent change, or just a transient problem?

Switching to the "Unanswered" view does display a list of questions, so this seems to be affecting only the "All Questions" view.

Comment: Are there actually any questions tagged with all four of those tags? That link is conducting an "and" search for all four tags. Keep in mind that [new nav was turned off today](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359643/retiring-new-navigation-beta-in-preparation-for-navigation-3-0) so if that link did something different through that feature, it's reverted to its normal behavior.

Comment: That link always did an "OR" until 18:30 UTC today.

Comment: If it did, then that was a function of new nav. The regular nav has always conducted an AND search. But you can always [turn it back into an OR search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+or+xml+or+perl+or+xslt) with relatively minor change.

Comment: Yep, based on your first comment I tried that and it works. If you think this question is worth keeping please post that as an answer so I can accept.  Otherwise let me know and I will delete the question.

Comment: I'm getting upvotes, so I guess other people are hitting the same issue.

Comment: I only up voted for the artistic screenshot with fancy border ...

Comment: Same problem here. My bookmarked searches stop working today. The reason is described above. The tags in each URL went from using OR to AND. I think this is the second or third time this year these links break due to some programming modification. Added the OR. Edited bookmarks. All set (until next time).

Comment: A work-around for the people like me who have lot of tags in their bookmarked URL, go [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sank8893/0ucq97ok/), then replace your URL with existing and click run. Then click the "SO Tagged questions" link in the result page and you know what is the next step.

Answer (score 9):

Since the question is getting upvotes, meaning other people are finding it helpful, and because upvotes on Meta don't accrue rep <sup>*(otherwise I would have let him/her post the answer)*</sup>, I've taken the liberty of copying @animuson's comments into an answer:

> That link is conducting an "and" search for all four tags. Keep in mind that new nav was turned off today so if that link did something different through that feature, it's reverted to its normal behavior
>
> The regular nav has always conducted an AND search. But you can always turn it back into an OR search with relatively minor change

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+or+xml+or+perl+or+xslt
```