# Topic list design

Tags: discussion

I've noticed this morning that my topic list got changed.

It used to be:

```
_________  _________  _________
|       |  |       |  |       | Topic title
| votes |  |answers|  | views | 
|_______|  |_______|  |_______| [tags]
```

Now it looks like this:

```
_________  
|       |  Topic title
| votes |  
|_______|  
_________  Part of topic text
|       |  
|answers|  
|_______|  [tags]

  views
```

Which makes, in my opinion, the topic list too long and obscure.

Is there a preference setting where I can choose the type of list that I'd like to see?

Comment: I think that was part of the new navigation (did you opt in to it?). It has been put to pasture.. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359643/retiring-new-navigation-beta-in-preparation-for-navigation-3-0

Comment: Look at the yellow box on the ===> right.

Comment: I've seen, and read that post, but that's more about the navigation, with the tabs and search function. Didn't find anything about the topic list. Well, if this is part of the transformation, so be it. Haven't have to like it though :)