# Tag filter view wasting screenspace compared to default view

Tags: feature-request

*I have posted this as [an answer in the new nav topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360286/16673) before, but I think it can be formulated as a feature request standing on its own.*

I was using the [retired new nav](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359643/retiring-new-navigation-beta-in-preparation-for-navigation-3-0) to quickly access questions with one tag. The same can be done now by clicking on the tag in my favourite tags. I think I can get used to that. What is hard to get used to is the fact that once I click on the tag, the question listing format is significantly different.

In the main navigation interface 11 questions fit on my screen vertically. With the tab filter interface (same as with any search) it is less than half - 5 only.

The difference can be most quickly illustrated by clicking on [Stack Overflow logo](https://stackoverflow.com/) and on the [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) button next to it.

A visual example - left side is the "questions", right side is the "main page":

[image: Questions listing] [image: Main page listing]

The request is to use the same layout  as the main page is currently using for questions and search results as well, or a similar one, if the same is not suitable for some reasons I cannot see.