# Refresh page doesn't reset current page

Tags: support

I am not sure if this is a *feature*, but it's something new (for some weeks already).

I have [bookmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) to start SO with [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tag (maybe important, maybe not). After looking first page I may go to page `2`, `3` and so on.

Earlier when refreshing page in browser (with <kbd>F5</kbd>) it was always resetting page to `1` and it was comfortable, as a kind of shortcut "go to page 1 and check new questions from whatever page".

But now it keeps me on the same page. This feels weird, because result of refresh is ... seeing questions what I already have seen.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna make an educated guess and say you were using the *New Navigation (beta)* feature, which has been discontinued. I recall it having a quirk in the pagination.

See [Retiring New Navigation (beta) in preparation for Navigation 3.0](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359643/retiring-new-navigation-beta-in-preparation-for-navigation-3-0?cb=1) for details.