# Whatever happened to saved question filters?

Tags: feature-request, questions, filtering

I don't remember when it happened (it was a long time ago), but suddenly I was no longer able to see my lists of filtered questions. Since I'm active in mainly low traffic tags, 99.99% of the time there are no questions I'm able to answer (or that I'm interested in answering) on the homepage. Zero, zip, nada.

What is more, there is no way for me to save any filter I apply to the page. So I'm forced to apply the same filter again and again from a txt file I keep on my google drive. Not very efficient, and has resulted in my answer rate plummeting.

Are there any plans to reinstate saved question filters in any form?

Comment: that was a [meta-tag:new-nav] feature. New nav was disabled so it could make place for the new-new-nav (properly versioned as [3.0](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359643/retiring-new-navigation-beta-in-preparation-for-navigation-3-0)), in 6 to 8 weeks ....

Comment: @rene thank you - I look forward to new-new-nav.

Comment: Can't you bookmark the page after applying the filter? AFAIK any changes you make to the search criteria is "saved" to the URL.

Comment: @Dukeling - although, see this answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/359648/569662 - this is what mine used to look like.

Comment: @tomredfern Since page titles of question list pages are similarly updated when there's a new question, you could potentially get the same effect by keep multiple tabs open in your browser (not a perfect substitute, but it might be good enough).