# Groups of favorite tags?

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

I like browsing questions by specific tags, but with variations of tagging this isn't always clear-cut.

Is there a way of creating groups of favorite tags, so I can have one-click filters for these?

for example I'd like a single view of ([oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oauth) + [oauth-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oauth-2.0)) or ([grape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grape) + [grape-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grape-api)) or ([python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) + [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x)) or ([c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) + [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) + [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) + [asp.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core)) or maybe ([c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) + [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)) (joking on that last one, zealots!!)

Comment: My workaround is browser bookmarks.

Comment: This was possible through tabs (like the ones hot, active etc.), and I was using it but it disappeared a couple of months ago.

Comment: Some of these can be set as wildcard favorites.. Like eg [oauth*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oauth+or+oauth-2.0+or+oauth2client+or+oauth-provider+or+oauth-1.0a+or+oauth2-playground+or+oauth.io+or+oauth-ruby+or+oauth2orize+or+oauth2-server+or+oauth2resttemplate+or+oauth2-toolkit+or+oauth-php+or+oauth2app+or+oauthtwitterwrapper)

Comment: @user2285236 Yep, when they removed the new nav in favor of the new new nav which they haven't released yet. They removed the new nav for a bogus reason, claiming they couldn't support it while they worked on the new new nav, somehow ignoring the best path of just leaving the new nav up for people without making any changes or fixes to it while building the new new nav from the ground up. The announcement for it is linked off to the right.

Comment: It would be cool if combining `c` and `c++` generates a new tag called `the mythological language that a lot of beginner seem to work with` :)

Answer (score 4):

See "OR operator" under [Advanced Search Options](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching).

You can do these and bookmark them:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oauth+or+oauth-2.0?sort=newest

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grape+or+grape-api?sort=newest

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+or+python-3.x?sort=newest

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+or+.net+or+asp.net+or+asp.net-core?sort=newest

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%20or%20c%2b%2b?sort=newest

Comment: that would work, though i'd have to do that in every browser on every device i've got :)  would be nice if here was a way in-site to do it :)

Comment: the old saved filter tabs does what you are describing, hopefully it will come back in the future https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/359648

Comment: @Joe You don't synchronize your bookmarks between devices?   Very easy to do with Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

At https://stackexchange.com/filters/new you can create filters from groups of tags. Example:

[image: SE “New filter” UI]

That lets you filter questions by tag groups across multiple SE sites. But it also allows you to limit your tag groups to just Stack Overflow questions if you want.

And it has the advantage of enabling you to get e-mail notifications when any new questions are created with any tags in your tag-group/filter.

But you don’t have to use that new-questions-notification feature if you don’t want to. You can instead just use the filter to browse (as requested in the question here). Example:

[image: SE filter browse]

And the tag-groups/filters you create also have public URLs you can give to other people. I have one at https://stackexchange.com/filters/203793/web-runtime that groups ~20 different tags.