# Where are all the bountied questions?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounty, stack-overflow-for-teams, user-experience

I opened Stack Overflow in a browser I don't usually and noticed a series of buttons that I don't have when logged in.

Not logged in and visiting [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)

[image: Not logged in]

---

Logged in and visiting [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)

[image: Logged in]

---

"Bounties" are hidden behind the "more" drop down when I'm logged in. Why is that? I hadn't realized there were missing until I wasn't logged in.

After bit of science, it seems that this is a symptom of being a member of a Team.

I think "Featured" should be shown to all users, otherwise they aren't really "featured" and aren't getting seen by everyone. Why are users that are on an SO Team not seeing the "Featured" tab any longer?

Comment: i am getting this fine... this isn't a window sizing issue or something?

Comment: Those screenshots were taken on the same machine at the same resolution.

Comment: must be a team thing then. as you say, you're in a team, i'm not and it looks fine for me

Comment: Yeah, with all that whitespace between the Questions amount and the filter buttons I'm not sure why they felt the need to hide all those filters. Honestly feel like this is more of a bug, frankly, even if it was intentional.

Answer (score 2):

We are in the midst of overhauling the question list UX that you mention. Only Teams users are exposed to the "simplified" ui with the "more" overflow. We are currently working on improving the filter/sorting ability and will add  saved tag searches (re-add if you previously used the [recently retired, perpetual beta "new" nav](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359643/retiring-new-navigation-beta-in-preparation-for-navigation-3-0)). So, you're stuck in the middle for now. We are actively working on this and hope to provide the new and improved functionality this summer.

Comment: Not sure it is right place but did you also change `tagged` part: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q05NN.png? Before it was nicely placed on right side(non-intrusive). Now it looks really ugly.

Comment: I love how the terminology evolves from 6 to 8 something to this summer :)

Comment: @JoeFriend  It looks better now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHsis.png