# Better separation of public and team contexts

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

When I joined a team on Stack Overflow, the landing page changed. This is what I expect when I come to SO:

[image: Non-team "Home" header]

[image: Non-team "Stack Overflow" header]

Now that I've joined a team, I see this instead:

[image: Team "Home" header showing questions from work]

[image: Team "Stack Overflow" header]

I often use SO at home as well as at work. When I access SO from home I do not want to be greeted by topics from my workplace. I also don't like the changes to the "Stack Overflow" header, or the fact that I have to confirm that I'm not accidentally asking a work question on the public SO whenever I create a new post.

I would enjoy using SO team much more if I could properly separate team and public contexts. One solution would be to provide a drop-down menu on my avatar in the upper right corner; then I could choose if I want to be xyz@gmail.com or xyz@my-company.com. Another solution would be to provide a custom domain such as: my-work.team.stackoverflow.com.

To help users not post work questions on the public SO, I think changing the page styling for team view would go a long way. You could let the team administrator choose from a few different themes, but they would all need to be pretty different from the public site style.

Whatever the solution, I really just want a complete separation of work and public SO.

Comment: Would the down voter care to comment? Is there an advantage to the current setup?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369403/where-are-all-the-bountied-questions

Comment: This is definitely something we're considering. We're still sorting out the best approach. I'm sorry I don't have a definitive answer at the moment, but I do want to assure you that we're trying to figure out how to better separate public and private content.